# How to Redirect from my own app to Settings General tab in setting swift 3.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, ios10

Hi I am not able to redirect from my app to General tab in setting. Here my code please help on this

I added prfes in url schema

```
guard let settingsUrl = URL(string:"prefs:root=General") else {
        return
    }

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {

         UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
             print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
         })

     }
```

Comment: UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList")!)
i tried this but no use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in iOS 10 they changed "prefs:" to "App-Prefs:"

> ```
>         guard let profileUrl = URL(string: "App-    
>          Prefs:root=General") else {
>             return
>         }
>
>          if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(profileUrl) {
>
>          UIApplication.shared.open(profileUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
>
>             print(" Profile Settings opened: \(success)")
>
>             })
>          }
> ```

Comment: Dont use this.. 

Using  Prefs/App-Pref falls under private API of apple. They rejected our app stating same reason.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
if let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(profileUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
            print(" Profile Settings opened: \(success)")
        })
    }
    print(url)
}
```

Comment: Hi Hiren, Thanks for your reply. i am able to navigate to the app setting but i want it to navigate directly to General Tab in settings. with your answer can redirect to app settings only

Comment: UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList")!)
i tried this but no use

Comment: use this may halpful : UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=General")!)